# Would ἀγάπη in 1 Cor. 13 be better translated חֶסֶד in Hebrew translations rather than אַהֲבָה?

Tags: greek, hebrew, pauline-epistles

I hope we can tolerate a translation question into another language besides English, especially since some people here know Hebrew.  It is even the 1st language for some here.

אַהֲבָה is the most common word for *love* in Hebrew, but it also means *like*. That is the word Delitzsch and the Bible Society in Israel use to translate ἀγάπη in 1 Cor. 13.  Many see ἀγάπη in 1 Cor. 13 as expressing God's love or at least the God kind of love.  חֶ֛סֶד seems more appropriate.

כִּ֣י אִם־בְּזֹ֞את יִתְהַלֵּ֣ל הַמִּתְהַלֵּ֗ל הַשְׂכֵּל֮ וְיָדֹ֣עַ אֹותִי֒ כִּ֚י אֲנִ֣י יְהוָ֔ה עֹ֥שֶׂה חֶ֛סֶד מִשְׁפָּ֥ט‬ וּצְדָקָ֖ה בָּאָ֑רֶץ כִּֽי־בְאֵ֥לֶּה חָפַ֖צְתִּי נְאֻם־יְהוָֽה׃
(Jer. 9:23, BHS2003)

כִּ֛י חֶ֥סֶד חָפַ֖צְתִּי וְלֹא־זָ֑בַח וְדַ֥עַת אֱלֹהִ֖ים מֵעֹלֹֽות׃
(Hosea 6:6, BHS2003)

Comment: Are you asking about modern Hebrew or ancient Biblical Hebrew? (I agree with your proposal for the old Hebrew.)

Comment: Delitzsch predates modern Hebrew.  The Bible Society is modern Hebrew.  Most here can only answer based on Biblical Hebrew.  However, I also welcome responses from Modern Hebrew, which is based on Biblical Hebrew with an additional almost 80 years of use.

Comment: I'm in no position to comment on the translation, but I do speak modern Hebrew and can clarify that אהבה (ahava) as the noun, is only used to mean love, and not liking/fondness which would be חיבה (khiba). As a verb אוהב (ohev), in modern Hebrew at least, can convey both liking/fondness or love, depending on the context.

Comment: @Bets -- OK, so I'm confusing the meaning of the verb with the noun.

Answer (score 4):

They possibly accounted for the Septuagint, since ἀγάπη consistently translates אַהֲבָה (*ahávah*)* in the 14 times it  appears in canonical books (2 Kingdoms/2 Samuel, Ecclesiastes, Song of Songs, Jeremiah).

In Hosea 6:6 חֶ֛סֶד (*khéset*) is translated in the Septuagint as ἔλεος - *mercy*, as is also the case in Jeremiah 9:23.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sup>אַהֲבָה is the noun form.  The verb form is אָהַב (*aháv*), which is translated ἀγαπάω (*agapao)* in the Septuagint; e.g. Deuteronomy 6:5 - וְאָ֣הַבְתָּ֔ אֵ֖ת יְהוָ֣ה אֱלֹהֶ֑יךָ בְּכָל־לְבָבְךָ֥ וּבְכָל־נַפְשְׁךָ֖ וּבְכָל־מְאֹדֶֽךָ׃ - καὶ **ἀγαπήσεις** κύριον τὸν θεόν σου ἐξ ὅλης τῆς καρδίας σου καὶ ἐξ ὅλης τῆς ψυχῆς σου καὶ ἐξ ὅλης τῆς ἰσχύος σου</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Both words are good candidates for translating ἀγάπη.  I will confine my comments to Biblical Hebrew.  It is possible that modern Hebrew has shifted these meaning slightly.  I will also assume that I do not need to expound the detailed meaning of a word like ἀγάπη to this audience, except to note that it never denotes, in NT Koine Greek, the kind of erotic love between a man and woman, even when such legitimate.

**אָהַב (ahav)**

The meaning of this word is extremely broad covering such situations as:

- the (legitimate) erotic love between a man and a woman, Gen 29:18, 20, 30, 32, etc
- the illicit love between a man and a woman, including in an adulterous relationship, eg, Gen 34:3, Hos 2:7, 9, 14, 15, Eze 23:5, 9, Jer 22;20, 22, etc
- love of bribes, Isa 1:23
- love of wisdom, Prov 4:6
- love of wine, Prov 21:17, Hos 3:1
- love of people platonically, Ruth 4:15
- love of tasty food, Gen 27:4, 9, 14
- love for God, Ex 20:6, Deut 5:10, 6:5, 7:9, Josh 22:5, etc
- Love of God for humans, Deut 4:37, 2 Sam 12:24, Prov 3:12, 15:9, etc

**חֵסֵד (Hessed)**

The meaning of this word is much more confined as it always means an elevated principled love, kindness, goodness, never an illicit nor selfish love. It is used of:

- kindness by showing favor and giving benefits between humans, 1 Sam 20:15, 2 Sam 16:17, etc
- kindness and mercy shown to the needy and miserable, Prov 11:17, 20:28, Job 6:14,  1 Kings 20:312, Hos 4:1, Isa 16:5, etc
- God's kindness and compassion to the needs of creation, Jonah 2:9, Ps 144:2, etc - this is its most common use

In choosing between these two I observe that חֵסֵד is a noun and while אָהַב is a verb which may influence the choice.  However, חֵסֵד is, closer in meaning to ἀγάπη because it contains much more other-centeredness and is never used of an illicit kind of love.

I also note that these two words are used in synonymous parallelism in Jer 31:3 (with both the noun and verb cognates of אָהַב and אַהֲבָה) -

> The LORD appeared to him long ago, saying, “I have **loved** you with
> an everlasting **love**; Therefore I have drawn you out with
> **loving-kindness**.

In the LXX, this is translated as:

> Κύριος πόρρωθεν ὤφθη αὐτῷ· **ἀγάπησιν** αἰώνιον **ἠγάπησά** σε, διὰ
> τοῦτο εἵλκυσά σε εἰς οἰκτείρημα.

Note that the final phrase, εἵλκυσά σε εἰς οἰκτείρημα = pull you into His possession does not correspond to the Hebrew.

We see these two words again in parallel in Ps 119:159 -

> Consider how I **love** Your precepts, O LORD; give me life according
> to Your **loving-kindness**.

The LXX translates this as:

ἴδε ὅτι τὰς ἐντολάς σου **ἠγάπησα**, Κύριε· ἐν τῷ **ἐλέει** σου ζῆσόν με.

Note that LXX uses ἀγάπη [love] and ἔλεος [mercy].  This is most often the case.  I assume that this was one of the main motivators for the Hebrew translation of the NT as the OP has noted.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case with modern Hebrew based on Biblical Hebrew, especially with common words independent of modern technology, it gives insight to Biblical Hebrew.  As Bets pointed out *like* is a meaning of the verb אהב but not the noun אהבה.  This is key to my issue with using אהבה to translate ἀγάπη in 1 Cor. 13.  Checking the lexicon's Biblical Hebrew is the same as modern Hebrew here.

> אַהֲבָה: f. ... —1. **loving** ... —2. **love**
> --
> Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In *The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament* (electronic ed., p. 18). E.J. Brill.

> אהב ... to **like**, to **love**
> -- Ibid.

Though not so much so, modern Greek, though grammatically quite different than Biblical Greek, can be insightful especially with common words.  A good example is καλός versus ἀγαθός.

Comment: Give Bets credit for his comment.